# Animate div on resize function

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate

I have the following that will resize the div to window size on click but I can't make it animate...

Any ideas?

```
$(function(){
    $("#trigger").click(function(){ 
        $(".more").height($(window).height());
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/gghm28ep/)

PS:

I tried something like this :

```
$(function(){
    $("#trigger").click(function(){ 
        $(".more").animate({
            $(this).height($(window).height());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate ?

Comment: @Blazemonger See update of what I tried with animate :)

Comment: You're not using `.animate` correctly -- reread the documentation.

Comment: @Blazemonger I kinda figured, I'm not that good with jquery...which is a big *boohoo* for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#trigger" ).click(function() {
    $(".more").animate({
        height: $(window).height()
    }, 1000, function() {
        // function that runs when animation finished
    });
});
```